# When I try to call a function, it says there is an error

Tags: python

To sum it up, I have little understanding in what I am doing so I will write a portion of the code so maybe anyone can see what's going on.

```
import sys
start = input("Continue? y/n ")
if start == "y":
   startp()
elif start == "n":
   print("Party pooper")
def startp():
   text = 'text\n'
   text2 = 'text2'

for char in text:
   sys.stdout.write(char)
   sys.stdout.flush()
   time.sleep(.1)

for char in text2:
   sys.stdout.write(char)
   sys.stdout.flush()
   time.sleep(.1)

startp()
```

If this is run, you can enter a letter/word, but the out come is

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/-/Desktop/--.py", line 4, in <module>
    startp()
NameError: name 'startp' is not defined
```

I think what I need to do is call the function after the user has typed `y` or `n` - but I have no idea how to, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: So where would I define it?

Comment: Could you help me to fix it though?

Comment: The other answers are doing an excellent job of that already, I don't need to add to that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is produced here:

```
if start == "y":
    startp()
```

because `startp` is defined below those lines of code.

You should always define the functions first (unless you have a reason to not do so). Also, `text` and `text2` aren't returned by the function, maybe you wanted to include the loops inside it?

```
import sys
def startp():
   text = 'text\n'
   text2 = 'text2'
   for char in text:
       sys.stdout.write(char)
       sys.stdout.flush()
       time.sleep(.1)
   for char in text2:
       sys.stdout.write(char)
       sys.stdout.flush()
       time.sleep(.1)

start = input("Continue? y/n ")
if start == "y":
   startp()
elif start == "n":
   print("Party pooper")
```

Comment: Thanks, I have a better understanding in what I am doing now, thank you all.

Answer (score 2):

As python create the functions in run time you can not call it before define the function.

```
if start == "y":
   startp()
       ^
```

Comment: @MartijnPieters No, they did define it after. I failed to see it as well.

Comment: @MalikBrahimi: ick, this is why empty lines are important.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Agreed, I thought it was another conditional.

Answer (score 0):

When you're reading a book, should you start with *they lived happily ever after* or *once upon a time*? Just as you would read a book, the compiler reads starting at the beginning and thus your function should be declared before it is used.

Answer (score 0):

You should define your function before calling it.

As the output says,`startp()` is not defined in the line 4 when you're trying to call it. Define your function before calling it and your code will be cleaner and probably will work better ;)